# calling time() of ctime, unpredictable behaviour in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

When I was working on a project using ctime lib I have noticed a strange bug that I cannot understand. After a while I understood that ctime is the cause of my trouble. When using time() function the behaviour of my code became inpredictable. The following is a sample code that I wrote:

```
1:    #include <ctime>
2:    #include <iostream>
3:    int main(int argc, char argv[])
4:    {
5:       std::cout << "Prova" << std::endl;
6:       time_t  timer1, timer2;
7:       timer1 = time(&timer1);
8:       timer2 = time(&timer2);
9:       while (true){
10:         double leak = difftime(timer2, timer1);
11:         std::cout << "Sleep: " << leak * 1000 << std::endl;
12:         time(&timer1);
13:         time(&timer2);
14:      }
15:      return 0;
16:   }
```

When try to debug it the istructons follow this sequence: ... 7 -> 8 -> 7 -> 8 -> 10 -> 11 -> 10 -> 11 -> 12 -> 13 -> 14 -> 8 ... Why istruction 7 and 8 are repeted twice? How can jump before the while? 
I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7 64 bit. This behaviour happen only when I build in Release mode. In Debug mode all work fine. 
What could it be? There is something that I don't know or I have mistaken something?

EDIT:
Here something similar to my work code.

```
void System::Run()
{
    time_t  timer1, timer2;
    timer1 = time(&timer1);
    timer2 = time(&timer2);
    while(!mbDone)
    {
      double leak = difftime(timer2, timer1); //I didn't check that is less than 50, but without wait the video go over 40/50 fps
      Sleep(50 - (leak * 1000)); //<- first time I'm expecting to wait nearly 50ms
      time( &timer1 );

      //Other work in between that work fine before
      //Grab image
      //Process image
      //Show image

      time(&timer2);
    }
}
```

From the debugger I see that when time(  ) is call the value is changed, but before of completing the cycle at some point it update another times, even if there aren't call of time.

Comment: What output were you expecting ?

Comment: Debugging optimized code rarely follows the source code exactly.  The optimizer is free to reorder many things for a faster result.  You really need to look at the disassembly to see what's going on.

Comment: @Chnossos
The output is not important here. The sequence of the instructions is.
7 -> 8 -> 10 -> 11 -> 12 -> 13 -> 14 -> 10 ... 
It jump before while condition. How could it happen?
In my code this broke everything

Comment: @RetiredNinja .. but the optimization are allowed to change code behaviour?

Comment: why do you think it changed the behavior or your code?

Comment: Does your code behavior change?  Is the output incorrect?  All the code you've shown does is compare two likely identical values forever.

Comment: I write a small sequence, but sometimes (and I don't figure out why) it doesn't complete the while block and jump out before

Comment: In this little example no, but in my full code set timer1 bigger than timer2 and this isn't what I want.

Comment: Forget what you think you are seeing in the debugger as far as which line is executing, in optimized code it will frequently be incorrect.  Does the code display incorrect results?  If this isn't the code you're seeing incorrect results from you need to post that code for a meaningful answer.

Comment: @3xpo The optimization is not allowed to change the behavior if the code otherwise doesn't do undefined behavior. *However* trying to debug optimized code is hard. The debugger will lie to you, it will present false information, it will not show you what's actually happening. Optimized code lose information that makes the debugger work properly.

Comment: `std::time` is the wrong thing to use for this purpose.  The value it returns is based on seconds and you are timing something that you expect to take milliseconds.  You should use something like `timeGetTime`, `GetTickCount`, or `QueryPerformanceCounter` instead.

Comment: If it was easy to debug in Release mode, why would we need Debug mode?

Comment: @n.m.I always debug in Debug mode. This time I noticed that the code stop working in Release mode. 
I'm a Java developer, I don't use C++ from 10 years. I don't remember code optimization :P

Comment: @RetiredNinja Initially I use clock() and CLOCK_PER_SEC. But something inside me put me on this way. Now I will use your suggestion. But I can't explain what happen in this code. After that I complete the work I will go to see the assembler code.

Answer (score 0):

I would try calling `time(0)` instead of passing an address. I don't know the internals of `time()` but when you pass an address, the value has to be stored twice. Passing a 0 avoids this.

Comment: Tomorrow I will try and update the question, thanks ;)

Comment: That shouldn't matter. `timer1 = time(&timer1);` is overkill, but it should be harmless. The call will store the current time in `timer1`; the same value will be assigned to `timer1`, but only after the call has completed.

Comment: I have noticed that now. It is a residual of a many try. I use timer1 = time(NULL) and time(&timer1). Same result